# Django Admin 'regroup' tag takes five arguments

Tags: django

I am trying to add a chart on django admin and i got this error. Following a tutorial on [here](https://www.neerajbyte.com/post/how-to-make-charts-in-django-admin-interface/) and doing the same steps, but got the error message.
If someone could help, i would owe you a lot! I don't know what should i change, in order to show the graph on my admin.

This is the line that fires the error and i don't know what i did wrong.

```
   {% regroup cl.queryset | dictsort: "location" by get_location_display as location_list %}

{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %} {% load staticfiles %} {% block extrahead %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var randomColorGenerator = function () {
        return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
    };
    var options = {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'left'
        },
        title: {
            display: true
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        }
    };
    window.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("location-chart");
        {% regroup cl.queryset | dictsort: "location" by get_location_display as location_list %}
        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: [{% for location in location_list %}'{{ location.grouper }}',{% endfor %}],
    datasets: [{
        data: [{% for location in location_list %}'{{ location.list|length }}', {% endfor %}],
        backgroundColor: [{% for location in location_list %}randomColorGenerator(), {% endfor %}]
                    }]
                },
    options: options
            });

</script> {% endblock %} {% block content %}
<h1> Graphs </h1>
<hr>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <canvas id="location-chart" style="width: 100px !important;"></canvas>
    </div>

</div>
{{ block.super }} {% endblock %}
```

This is my admin:

```
class ParkingModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):


    list_display = ["user", "location","parking_on"]
    list_display_links = [ "location"]
    list_editable = [ "parking_on"]
    list_filter = ["location"]
    search_fields = ["location", "parking_on"]
    date_hierarchy = 'parking_on'
    save_as = True
    save_on_top = True
    change_list_template = 'admin/change_list_graph.html'

    class Meta:
        model = Parking
```

My models.py:

```
class Parking(models.Model):
    PARKING_PLOT = (
        ('P1', 'Parking #1'),('P2', 'Parking #2'), ('P3', 'Parking #3'),
        ('P4', 'Parking #4'),('P5', 'Parking #5'), ('P6', 'Parking #6'),
        ('P7', 'Parking #7'),('P8', 'Parking #8'), ('P9', 'Parking #9'),
        ('P10', 'Parking #10'),('P11', 'Parking #11'), ('P12', 'Parking #12'),
        ('P13', 'Parking #13'),('P14', 'Parking #14'), ('P15', 'Parking #15')

    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=True, default=1, on_delete=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    parking_on = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please select the date you want to come in the office.',)
    parking_off = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please select the date when you leave')
    numar_masina = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="IF77WXV", blank=True, null=True,help_text='Please insert your license plate number')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, default="P1", null=True, choices=PARKING_PLOT,help_text='Please select the desired parking plot.')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = ParkingManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove spaces around {% regroup cl.queryset|dictsort: "location" by get_location_display as location_list %}

You had spaces around as : cl.queryset | dictsort.

Hope it helps.